# GridView sorting without JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, gridview-sorting

When "AllowSorting" is true on an asp.net GridView, it just makes the headers with a SortExpression clickable.

Trouble is that it does this with JavaScript links - so with JS turned off you cannot sort the columns.

Before I go and write my own HeaderTemplate to use Querystrings instead of JavaScript, am I missing an easier way of being able to sort a GridView without any relyance upon JavaScript?

Thanks
bgs264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the links with your own template which can contain buttons and then perform the sorting on the server side.